# How do I know the url I need to call an api deployed in CloudHub using anypoint platform? (MuleSoft)

Tags: integration, mule-studio, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

I want to make a request to another api deployed in cloudhub but I am not sure how to call it because I don`t know where is the url,is it possible to get in anypoint platform?

Answer (score 1):

If your application is deployed on CloudHub with a shared load balancer, you can find the URL by navigating to Anypoint Platform → Runtime Manager → Your Application → Settings → App URL (host name).

In the case of CloudHub 1.0, the App URL typically has the format:
`<app_name>.<region_code>.cloudhub.io`

Your request URL should be formatted like this: `<protocol>://<app_url>/<resource or endpoint>`

Please note that your application, deployed in CloudHub, must be listening on host 0.0.0.0 and either the HTTP port (8081) or the HTTPS port (8082).

Comment: I clicked on the app url and I see this 502 Bad Gateway
We couldn't find any Cloudhub application listening on this API.

Comment: Simply clicking the app URL, won't work. In this case, you should anticipate receiving a "502 Bad Gateway - We couldn't find any Cloudhub application" error message.

Make sure to append the appropriate resource or endpoint to your app_url.

For instance, assuming you're using the HTTP protocol, your app URL is "test123.us-e2.cloudhub.io," and it's listening on the "hello" resource or endpoint, the correct URL format would be: http://test123.us-e2.cloudhub.io/hello 

Try first calling this app from a REST client ( such as Postman) and see if you are able to invoke it or not. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, obtaining the app URL from the Anypoint platform is entirely feasible. To do so, follow these steps:

1. Log in to the [Anypoint platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulON5.png).
2. Navigate to the "Runtime Manager" section.
3. Locate your application's name and click on it.
4. Access the "Settings" menu.
5. You will find the App URL displayed, as illustrated in the image below.

[image]

However, it's important to note that merely knowing the application URL isn't sufficient for making calls to it. You must also be aware of whether it operates over HTTP or HTTPS protocols and the specific resource or endpoint it listens to. If any policies are enforced on that API, such as client ID requirements, you should be familiar with those details as well.

Assuming the application is accessible over the public Internet and is using the HTTP protocol, if your app URL is "test123.us-e2.cloudhub.io" and it listens on the "hello" resource or endpoint, the correct URL format would be http://test123.us-e2.cloudhub.io/hello

For a more comprehensive understanding, I recommend performing a Proof of Concept (POC) in your personal account and attempting to call the application using a REST client like Postman.

You might also find this informative [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/OAwplg66xfM?si=x7QMklKZJE460he7) helpful in gaining a better grasp of the process; I encourage you to watch it.

Once you've successfully invoked the API outside of MuleSoft to ensure its functionality, you can utilize the HTTP Request connector to make calls to that API.

For detailed instructions on configuration, please consult the following documentation and refer to this informative [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/FzMPB21UO_4?si=eSBpHyfWp5EZ0TFI).

[HTTP Request Connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/http-connector/0.3.9/http-request-connector)

[Configure HTTP Request Operation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/http-connector/1.7/http-request-ref)

[CALL EXTERNAL HTTP REST API](https://mulesy.com/call-http-rest-service/)

Thank you!